# Need help with this calc 3 question! It deals with projectile motion with 3 different objects being thrown and vectors.

Tags: calculus, vectors, projectile-motion

How high would the object be thrown if three objects are to be juggled at 120 beats per minute( each object is thrown in turn one at a time and one per beat) with a horizontal displacement of approximately 0.30 m? use g = 9.8m/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time each object needs to spend in the air is 3 beats (I ignore the horizontal movement between hands), which means $T=1.5s$. Let's call $v$ the vertical velocity when thrown upwards. When the object lands in the other hand it will have a velocity $-v$ (assuming no air resistance). For constant acceleration $g$ you have $$-v=v-gT$$or $$v=\frac{gT}{2}$$ The maximum height is reached at $t=T/2$. The formula for height in a constant acceleration is $$h=vt-\frac12 gt^2$$
All that's left is to plug in the numbers